# How to load the custom fonts in the framework in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, custom-font

I am developing the custom framework and wants to import the custom font from the project settings.

I've followed all the below steps :

```
     * Added external fonts into the project folder.
     * Added into the build targets.
     * Fonts are added in the Copy bundle resources in the project target settings.
     * Fonts are added in the Property list
```

But always getting nil object.
If I am trying in the normal app it's working fine. When I am trying to import into my custom framework and it's not working.

Please advice.

```
extension UIFont {
   static let systemFontRegular = "SFProText-Regular"{
   return UIFont(name: systemFontRegular, size: size)!
  }
}
```